# Expression is not allowed in a variable outside of a function

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I want to link the directory to the $screenshotPath string, but an error in PHPStorm shows up: expression is not allowed as field default value. How can I fix it? Code:

```
use PHPUnit\Extensions\SeleniumTestCase;
use ApplicationTest\Bootstrap;

class AdminLoginLogoutTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase {
    protected $captureScreenshotOnFailure = true;
    //$screenshotPath is giving me this error...
    protected $screenshotPath = __DIR__ . "/FailedTestsScreenshots";
    protected $screenshotUrl = "http://icho/screenshots";

    protected $path = "http://icho";

    protected function SetUp() {
        $this->setBrowser( "*firefox" );
        $this->SetBrowserUrl( $this->path );
    }

    public function testAdminLoginLogout() {
        $this->open( "/admin" );
        $this->type( "name=username", "test" );
        $this->type( "name=password", "test" );
        $this->click( "id=submitbutton" );
        $this->waitForPageToLoad( "30000" );
        $this->assertEquals( "Dashboard", $this->getText( "link=Dashboard" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "Haios", $this->getText( "link=Haios" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "POs", $this->getText( "link=POs" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "Staco's", $this->getText( "link=Staco's" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "Mail templates", $this->getText( "link=Mail templates" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "Mailings", $this->getText( "link=Mailings" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "Sytem texts", $this->getText( "link=System texts" ) );
        $this->assertEquals( "Advanced admin", $this->getText( "link=Advanced admin" ) );
        $this->click( "css=a[title='Sign Out']" );
        $this->click( "id=bot2-Msg1" );
        $this->waitForPageToLoad( "30000" );
        $this->assertEquals( "Login is vereist", $this->getText( "css=h2" ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to decrale it during `setUp()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move it into to the constructor (or any other function) - you seem not to have any constructor for the class, but `__construct` will be called anyway :

```
protected $screenshotPath = '';

public function __construct() {
    $this->$screenshotPath = __DIR__ . "/FailedTestsScreenshots";
}
```

or into `SetUp()` :

```
protected function SetUp() {
    $this->$screenshotPath = __DIR__ . "/FailedTestsScreenshots";
    $this->setBrowser( "*firefox" );
    $this->SetBrowserUrl( $this->path );
}
```

Comment: The thing is Selenium doesn't recognize them if they are not outside a function

Comment: @Milen you declare `$screenshotPath` as above, just with an empty value `protected $screenshotPath = ''`; and then you set the desired value in the function or constructor.